# Code for determining the latest file in a folder where the files are numbered sequentially

Tags: batch

I would like to have code that I could use in a batch file that will first look for the newest file numbered sequentially in a specific folder and delete the remaining files.

I download podcasts and quite often there are several in a specific folder at any given time, all with the same name but preceded by a random number.

I would like to be sure that I am working with the latest file in this folder for my remaining batch processes that I have already created.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544268/sorting-a-list-in-progressive-numeric-order/23578118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something similar to:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od /t:c') do set LAST=%%i
echo The most recently created file is %LAST%
```

Where the parameters for the `dir` command are:

- to list just the names - `/b`
- of just the files - `/a-d`
- sorted by date (oldest first) - `/od`
- based on the creation time (/t:c)

The name of the newest file is stored in the LAST variable,
overwriting the previous one.
When the loop finishes, the LAST variable contains the name of the
newest file.

Comment: You may use the above code to create input to wget, but that's another question.

Comment: Using the above code, how could I modify it so that the %LAST% variable is only used if the date is today's date only?

Comment: This is much more complicated.